# Javadoc @link to Method with List of Object

Tags: java, list, javadoc

My java Method is:

```
public void openUrlIfDifferent(String pageKey, List<GherkinStepCondition> conditions) throws TechnicalException, FailureException {
    goToUrl(pageKey, false);
}
```

My OK javadoc is:

```
{@link noraui.browser.steps.BrowserSteps#openUrlIfDifferent(String, List) openUrlIfDifferent}
```

But I want keep List of **GherkinStepCondition** (`List<GherkinStepCondition>`)

I try with `{@link noraui.browser.steps.BrowserSteps#openUrlIfDifferent(String, List&lt;noraui.gherkin.GherkinStepCondition&gt;) openUrlIfDifferent}` **but is KO**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it and there is no reason to.

```
{@link noraui.browser.steps.BrowserSteps#openUrlIfDifferent(String, List) openUrlIfDifferent}
```

In the rendered Javadoc this displays as a link that says `openUrlIfDifferent`. If you click it, it will open the Javadoc of your method.

The link is unambiguous without the generic type parameters, since you can't overload your method with just changing the generic type of the list parameter. E.g. if you define a second method like this

```
public void openUrlIfDifferent(String pageKey, List<String> conditions) {}
```

you'll get a compile error.